# Openpyxl creating table with style generate unexpected color

Tags: excel, styles, openpyxl

I am using examples in [openpyxl official example](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/worksheet_tables.html) to create a style table in excel. For style, i am using the following

```
style = TableStyleInfo(name="TableStyleMedium13", showFirstColumn=False,
                   showLastColumn=False, showRowStripes=True, showColumnStripes=False)
```

I get the following result. Indicating I am actually get a style `Aqua, Table Style Medium 13`. However, I do not specify the `Aqua` color. What I want is the default `blue` color.
[image]

If I open a new excel and format a table, the drop down of table style will gives me `Blue, Table Style Medium 13`, which is what I want. But in the python script, I don't find the place to specify `color` option for `TableStyleInfo`, and it just default to `Aqua`.

[image]

Anyone help me out?

Comment: The colours used depend upon the the theme used: you can this with Light 3.

Comment: But when I open an excel and press `Ctrl + T`, there is the `Blue, Table Style Medium 13`

Comment: The colour comes from the theme.

Comment: Does it mean there is actually no `Blue` color for `Medium 13` at all?

Comment: It's all defined in the theme.

Comment: @CharlieClark is there a way in Openpyxl to use Built-in Table styles?